# Joomla if else for menu by ID or url

Tags: php, url, joomla, if-statement

I have a situation whereby i want two of my pages to look different form the rest but they are not front pages. If they were it would be easy as the code below would do the trick.

```
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
echo 'This is the front page';

esle(do something else)
 }
?>
```

In short i want a similar approach but this time, to get the menu by ID/URL. Any ideas?

Comment: please specify the Joomla version you are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer to this...all you need to check is the menu ID then put the code below.

```
<?php
  //This is the code for the page with menu ID 6
  $menuID = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
  if ($menuID == '6')
  {
    echo '';
  }
  elseif ($menuID == '2') //This is the HTML for page with menu ID 2
  {
    echo '';
  }
  elseif ($menuID  == '4') //THis is the html for page with menu id 4
  {
    echo '';
  }
  else  //This is the HTML code for the rest of the pages
  {
    echo '';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Joey that works great but how can I add multiple id's to some, I've tried `($menuID == '5, 20, 25')` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @bybe all you have to do is use the or PHP operator. something like this
    ($menuID == '5' | '20' | '25'){//place your code here}

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks for getting back to me. I've tried `if($menuID== '115' | '116' | '117' | '118' | '119'){echo'http://schema.org/Product';}else{echo'http://schema.org/LocalBusiness';}` but else doesn't seem to work. All pages using product and ignoring else. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Page ItemId can be obtained using `$itemid = JRequest::getInt( 'Itemid' );`