# How can I use PHP to place specific HTML on Certain Pages of my Template?

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.3

There are two ways of writing php snippets to place html on the home page and then html on all other pages... This is for Joomla 3.++

```
<?php
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
echo 'HTML for HOME PAGE HERE'; 
} else {
echo 'HTML for ALL OTHER PAGES HERE';
} ?>
```

This code allows for just focusing on the home page only:

```
<?php
$menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo 'HTML FOR HOME PAGE HERE';
}
?>
```

What I would like to do, specifically like the second code snippet, is focus on specific pages on the site....

The reason being is A. I don't want to create a template for every other page type I am creating... And B. I don't want to have to place template elements of styling in my html module positions.  I feel the custom HTML or blog / article posts should simply be for content insertion.

So is there a way to instead of calling on the $menu->getDefault()) <<<< make that getPage???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  You can do a direct page edit and ifelse edits for multiple pages.

```
<?php
//This is the code for the page with menu ID 102
$menuID = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
if ($menuID == '102')
{
echo '<strong>long</strong>';
}
?>
```

Here is the code for multiple pages.

```
<?php
//This is the code for the page with menu ID 6
$menuID = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
if ($menuID == '6')
{
echo '';
}
elseif ($menuID == '2') //This is the HTML for page with menu ID 2
{
 echo '';
 }
 elseif ($menuID  == '4') //THis is the html for page with menu id 4
 {
 echo '';
 }
 else  //This is the HTML code for the rest of the pages
 {
echo '';
}
?>
```

Found the answer here.

[Joomla if else for menu by ID or url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447451/joomla-if-else-for-menu-by-id-or-url)

Comment: is there any performance hits for this solution?  As well, I am assuming that I can cut out the last else statement because I don't have the major html on its on and this is only needed where I want to put the html at for other pages.  Is this the correct way to understand this?

Comment: Is there any disadvantages to doing it this way?  like many php calls?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JInput` to get the page information from the request.

Comment: so what would that statement look like in its entirety?

Comment: Assuming you have $app, and depending on what you want to select based on something like  `if ($app->input->getInteger($Itemid) == 105) { ...}`  or `if ($app->input->getString($option) == 'com_weblinks') { ...}`